# Pythonic way to calculate average

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the average of the values inside of the tuples in this list

```
[('coinbasepro', 10822.0), ('bitstamp', 10832.82)]
```

What would be the most pythonic way (like lambdas, reduce, list comprehensions) to do this simple operation?

Comment: sum itemgetter len

Comment: coding style is not really on-topic for this forum. In general good coding style is about "can the next person who looks at this code quickly and accurately determine what it is accomplishing?" and also "is this code written in a way that the language it is written in can compute the result in a reasonably efficient manner?" Take care to answer those two questions for yourself, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: `statistics.mean(x for _,x in data)` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
data = [('coinbasepro', 10822.0), ('bitstamp', 10832.82)]
average = np.mean([i[1] for i in data])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that doesn't not require any extra packages (assuming your list will always be in this format):

```py
l1 = [('coinbasepro', 10822.0), ('bitstamp', 10832.82)]
nums = [x[1] for x in l1]
avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)

print(avg)
# 10827.41
```